# Disable auto correct in smart typing apk - without settings

Tags: apk

I have a samsung - android 6- with no settings in it (yes I deleted it) .is there any apk where I can control the smart typing or auto correction (ON/OFF)?

Comment: What do you mean, you deleted the settings? The Android settings? Otherwise, this would depend on the keyboard app... For example, in Gboard you would get the keyboard open, press the Google icon, then the 3-dot overflow menu, then Settings and make your changes accordingly, however many keyboards (and other apps) rely on the Android Settings app as their interface, it might not work no matter you do.

Comment: Yes Sir, I rooted the device and deleted the settings. Can I use this app if no settings are present

Comment: I would suggest getting your settings back, even if you have to reflash stock image.

Comment: I strongly agree with @acejavelin here: no use to doctor the symptoms. Especially with a central thing like settings, you won't find an end. Restore the backup you made before tampering with root powers (*ugh, ugh* yeah, none made, right?), replace what you've deleted (if you remember what it was and can obtain the exact same files), or re-flash your very same ROM (dirty flash should be fine if flashing the *exact same* ROM, so no data lost) – but don't try to find "ugly work-arounds" where real solutions are available.

Answer (score -2):

Though I deleted the settings - for some reason :)- I installed Gboard & I think may be Swiftkey will work too & it worked after several trials.
Thank you all.